# i was solving a sequence of large numbers, but python shell stop responding

Tags: python-2.7, math

I am a python newbie
How to deal with large numbers in python?

If i need to calculate  the value of   `n*(2**(n-1))%m` 
where,

```
n=1000000000000000009 m=1000000007
```

when i was dealing with small value of n up to 
    n=1000009
it works but python shell stops responding for higher values

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Any guess about what happenning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) method. Python builtin `pow` does that for you:

> pow(x, y[, z]) -> number
>
> With two arguments, equivalent to `x**y`.  With three arguments,
>      equivalent to `(x**y) % z`, but may be more efficient (e.g. for longs).

Here is a non builtin implementation (copied from [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/crypto/Code/FastPow_Python.html)):

```
def f(x,e,m):
    X = x
    E = e
    Y = 1
    while E > 0:
        if E % 2 == 0:
            X = (X * X) % m
            E = E/2
        else:
            Y = (X * Y) % m
            E = E - 1
    return Y
```

Finally, what you need is

```
>>> n=1000000000000000009
>>> m=1000000007
>>> n*pow(2,n-1, m) % m
783433706L
```

Comment: Note if anyone should want to use this with Python 3 or with [`from future import division`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238), you'd have to use `E//2` instead of `E/2`. Otherwise the division will convert to float, causing an inaccurate result. Since the original question is tagged python 2.7, OP will likely not be affected.

Comment: I copied the implantation mostly to explain the algorithm, I didn't try it and the performance will be most likely be slower than the builtin version.

Answer (score 1):

`n*(2**(n-1))` will be **huge**, so computing this the naive way will fail. Instead, you should try to split this up into reasonably sized chunks of work, and compute the modulo operation after each such chunk. A common technique here is binarization: you compute `2%m`, `4%m=((2%m)*(2%m))%m`, `16%m=((4%m)*(4%m))%m`, `256%m=((16%m)*(16%m))%m` and so on, and then multiply those values for which `(n-1)` has a bit set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the lag may just be Python taking time to calculate the massive numbers you're dealing with.

Comment: The result is quite small actually due to the mod !

Comment: That's true, but it has to evaluate a huge number to get there. Though due to the mod, my printing concerns are moot.